# Has the word “supposably” really been added to the Oxford Dictionary?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, dictionaries

I used to always correct my illiterate friends whenever they would say the word “supposably” instead of supposedly, by snarkingly saying, “There’s no B in suposeDly!” Then I read that one of the big dictionary companies actually added that ignorant sounding word? Please tell me that I misread something, somewhere?

Comment: Note that the posted question is asking specifically whether major dictionaries now recognize use of _supposably_ as interchangeable with _supposedly_ (in the sense of "allegedly" or "purportedly" or "accepted as true by some people")—not whether such dictionaries recognize _supposably_ (in the sense of "conceivably") as a legitimate word, as Merriam-Webster, for one, certainly does. I think this is a legitimate question, and accordingly I am voting to reopen it.

Comment: Regardless of whether the question is reopened or not, you may find [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/supposably-vs-supposedly#:~:text=So%20in%20summation%3A%20supposably%20is,served%20by%20using%20supposedly%20instead.) to be an interesting read.

Comment: @SvenYargs The title of this question seems to contradict your description of it. The only mention of "supposedly" is in OP's description of conversations with friends, which appears to be provided merely as background. I'm voting to close again.

Comment: You misread something somewhere. Whether it was about *supposably* I don't know. This needs clarification and doesn't meet standards for an acceptable question - no research, vague, ranty.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Other site participants have sometimes chided me for answering the question asked in the headline of a posted question rather than in the body of the question—so I take your point about the mismatch here between "Has the word 'supposably' really been added to the OED?" and "Do major dictionaries now endorse using 'suposably' interchangeably with 'supposedly'?" (which is the gist of the body of the posted question). Still, if the mismatch troubled me in this case, I might be more inclined to revise the headline to match the point of the question than to close the question.

Comment: @SvenYargs I agree, but the body of the question has flaws, too. E.g., it contains two question marks, both of which conclude questions that aren't suitable for this site, either. So I think that this needs some major, not minor, revisions, which I think are better suited for OP to make than me. If it's improved, then of course I'd be happy to retract my CV.

Comment: See https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/supposably-vs-supposedly

Answer (score 2):

The *OED* has examples of *supposably* going back to 1696.  [And *supposable* back to 1627.]

*Supposably* is labeled: "Now chiefly *U.S.*"

So ... I would avoid using "ignorant" for people who use this word.

Comment: I can't add an 'answer', but [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/supposably-vs-supposedly#:~:text=So%20in%20summation%3A%20supposably%20is,served%20by%20using%20supposedly%20instead.) has a very good usage note. It includes 'What does supposably mean? That’s where things get a bit tricky. In most early uses supposably appears to have a meaning that is distinct from supposedly, having the intended meaning of “capable of being conceived of.” Many people who use the word today, however, appear to intend it to mean something that is ...

Comment: much closer to supposedly (“allegedly”). This modern sense bothers some people.' // I'm not sure 'supposably' is used frequently enough to be included in Oxford Languages Dictionary or OALD(?) But it doesn't flatline in [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=supposably&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).